# How much does the Winter Bash skew SF&F Site stats?

Tags: discussion

It seems the Winter Bash encourages frivolous activities on a site that is serious, or fairly serious for the rest of the year. How do Winter Bash statistics compare to and impact the SF&F years statistics? (I'm not complaining. I'm curious as I count my pile of hats along with a lot of you.)

Comment: Well, for starters, I voted for your question *solely* for the purpose of earning a hat.

Comment: @PeregrineRook lol. I'm here for ya, bud.

Comment: "a site that is serious, or fairly serious for the rest of the year" - are you and I on the same site? :)

Comment: @DVK Shhhh. I'm wearing my hat gathering hat today. Seriously.

Comment: @MajorStackings - meh. Hats are a trivial and unimportant thing.

Comment: @DVK I know. I know. I say that every year, and every year I end up chasing them down the rabbit hole.

Comment: I’m struggling to get the raw data of the site analytics page to do a proper analysis, but it doesn’t look like it has much of an effect.

Comment: @DVK - I decided not to bother with hats this year. That said, I've still managed to win a dozen of the buggers without even trying/

Comment: @Richard - I deliberately tried for about 5-7 hats. All my others are basically accidental.

Comment: @DVK - Your hat-whoring is well known and documented.

Comment: @DVK "Hats are a trivial and unimportant thing" - [is it still the same person using the DVK account](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/whats-needed-to-get-a-bill-lumbergh-hat#comment14450_5320)? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - yes, but I have more fun things to do this december, clearly