# What caused a spike of traffic on 28 June 2012?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the [site analytics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (25k users only, sorry) while trying to work out [whether Winter Bash skews the stats](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7760/3567).

There are a couple of noticeable spikes in the traffic graph:

[image]

The spike in the last month or so is [some low-budget indie film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens).

I’m more interested in the spike on 28 June 2012. There’s a comparable spike in posts, but less so in votes. **What happened?**

---

The stats page lists a few milestones that might have caused a traffic blip, but all at the wrong time:

- 11 Jan 2011 – private beta
- 18 Jan 2011 – public beta
- 13 Dec 2011 – graduation

Comment: [Graph of Futurama questions by month](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/485840/questions-with-a-specific-tag-by-month?TagName=futurama#graph)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### This was an event related to Futurama.

I looked on the [list of questions ordered by date](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=435&sort=newest) and noticed a lot of Futurama questions on 28 June 2012. Personally I wasn't around at that time, but I've heard about this event from DVK, who said:

> *sigh.* I was SOOOO hoping that the Trauma of Futurama was fully behind us :( Basically, we got overflooded with Futurama questions, many of questionable quality, as part of a promotional event.
> <sub>-- DVK, 7 Dec 2015</sub>

For more details, have a look at the various meta posts thrown up by [this search](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=futurama+is%3Aquestion). Notice the date stamps: they're all in June or July 2012. In particular, here are two posts from 28 June. [Congratulations on being mentioned on Futurama's Facebook page!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/congratulations-on-being-mentioned-on-futuramas-facebook-page) says:

> https://www.facebook.com/Futurama/posts/313500278739993
>
> I was browsing Facebook this evening and noticed a link to the SciFi Stack Exchange on Futurama's newsfeed! Congratulations - this should bring a good bit of traffic.

And then the results of this promotion. [Holy monkeys Batman! That is A LOT of posts!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/holy-monkeys-batman-that-is-a-lot-of-posts) says:

> I think due to what happened here: [Congratulations on being mentioned on Futurama's Facebook page!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1971/3383), or most probably here: https://www.facebook.com/Futurama/posts/320014191418612
>
> We are getting **MANY** [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) posts within the past few minutes.

Comment: from what I remember, this quickly went from "awesome we were mentioned on Futurama's page!" to "oh s#$ we were mentioned on Futurama's page." to "dear god make it stop make it stop". It was around that time that I learned how to ignore the futurama tag.

Comment: I think I *still* have it on Ignore since that terrible, terrible time. Pointless, pointless questions everywhere!

Comment: -10000 for making me remember that atrocity.

Comment: @DVK - I'm sad I missed it. I like futurama :-)

Comment: @Richard -- You wouldn't like it after experiencing *Futuretrauama* ...

Comment: @Slytherincess - Honestly, I've had a look at the question from around the time period. Some of them actually looked quite decent.

Comment: @Richard maybe there were lots of deleted ones too?

Comment: @randal'thor - I had a look at the deleted ones as well. There's more than a few that got closed by trigger-happy regulars that might have survived if they'd been asked today.

Comment: @Richard Well, I suppose that balances out the many old highly-voted questions and answers that'd be DVed to the pits if they'd been asked today ...

Comment: Is this a treasure trove of deleted questions that ought to be reopened? The only thing data.SE won't help with is finding deleted posts. :-/

Comment: @amarillo I wasn't around at that time, but the comments above, as well as what I've heard in chat, give the impression that this is ***anything but*** a treasure trove of worthwhile questions.